# Salesforce - Limit_Exceeded - Error

Tags: limits, dmlexception

I have piece of code for inserting case from back end -

I checked the logs - and the error is as below

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: LIMIT_EXCEEDED, limit exceeded: []

This error is only for one of the sandbox and not in all sandboxes.

I checked system over view - and no limit is exceeded.  I also tried to research if we are hitting the email limit , but could not find it in the system

Comment: There are lots of kinds of limits beyond email limits. You could have hit a SOQL limit, or some other kind of limit that prevented the DML from occurring, thus causing the DML exception. Look deeper into your debug logs.

Comment: Error message says DMLException so the limit is likely to be # of rows inserted in the transaction exceeds your edition's limits. The reason it fails in one sandbox versus another could be due to the data being different in each sandbox

Comment: Could be the total accumulated DML in the execution context for that matter, not just in that particular operation where it entered that class.

Comment: I would suggest to take a look to the triggers too. Maybe you're doing a logic on Before/After insert of the cases, and you're processing records without any precaution on Salesforce Governor Limits.

Comment: Thankyou all for the inputs - Issue was with Routing Limit exceeded in Omni Routing which led to case creation failure

Answer (score 0):

We got this issue today and the root cause for this is mentioned in below link.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000317857&type=1

When error messages says `LIMIT_EXCEEDED, limit exceeded: []` with no more info, check your Omni Channel limits. Make sure its less than defined number. And proceed with given resolution steps to resolve this.

The exact error message here from Salesforce logs is :

`Exceeded MAX_PENDING_SERVICE_ROUTINGS of 200000`""`"common.exception.LimitExceededException: Exceeded MAX_PENDING_SERVICE_ROUTINGS of 200000`